# How can i load a function that starts from loadstart to loadstop in inAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I am loading a pdf from google drive in cordova inappbrowser. I want to hide the sign in button. I call this code at my loadstop and it works.

```
function loadPDF(url){
    // var myCallback = function() {
    //     setTimeout(function(){ 
    //         var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('drive-viewer-toolstrip-rgt-panel'), i;
    //         for (var i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i ++) {
    //             appBanners[i].style.display = 'none';
    //         }
    //     },500);
    // }

    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no', 'hidden=yes');
    // ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
    //     ref.executeScript({code: myCallback});
    // });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
        ref.insertCSS({code: ".drive-viewer-toolstrip-rgt-panel{display: none !important;opacity: 0 !important;}"});
    });
}
```

But the issue is that the button appears for 1 or 2 seconds. I don't want that. I used the executeScript as well to hide the button element but it doesn't work for some reason. Can any1 help me here? I am taking help from [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) but I can't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried out invoking the event on loadstart instead of loadstop? Jus check out the sample here - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#example-1

Comment: @Gandhi yes I did, but the pdf starts to load after some time, so it doesn't work at loadstart.

Comment: May be you can try out placing timeout in the loadstart event listener to tackle this as there are only four events available in inappbrowser plugin and this is the best place

Comment: If you are looking for more control, then you may have to look at this option - https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Comment: I tried that as well @Gandhi but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: You may upload a sample project for us to check